# (Date.today + 6).year how to get the years last 2 digits

Tags: ruby

Im working with tests for credit cards in database.

I just need the last 2 number from the following integer.

```
3.2.21@2.1.3 (#<PlanForm::Voucher:0x007f8f41b)> (Date.today + 6).year
=> 2015
```

So the above should return `15`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this?

```
(Date.today + 6).year % 100
# => 15
```

Comment: best approach by far, more palatable than the other approaches exposed

Comment: Will return only one digit (0) for 1900, 2000, 2100 etc. `(Date.today + 6).strftime('%y')` is the correct answer for this.

Comment: @msdundar OP accepted this answer which, like every other answer here, returns an integer. Consider that you might be solving a different problem than the OP needed solved.

Answer (score 11):

```
(Date.today + 6).strftime("%y").to_i
```

Comment: @Gagan, you may be right, but how many readers will know what "%y" means? I guess they could look it up, as I did, and in doing so, learn something new. On balance, I think this and Jordan's answer are running neck-and-neck.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Yes you are right at your place I just said this is the rails way and `strftime` provide this feature so it's better to use this then do something else. this was my thinking. anyways all posters answers are correct and there are many different ways to achieve it's upto user which is more preferable for him.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `strftime` is a standard way (as in, it is not a Ruby thing; it is a programming thing) to translate time and date into string representations. It's generally a better approach for stuff like this because it has a higher chance of being comprehensible to whoever comes across your code in the future.

Comment: @richardjones, I wrote that some time ago and now wonder why I thought `"%y"` would seem so mysterious to readers. I don't think I was criticizing the use of `strftime`, an essential method and certainly much preferred to `parse`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is one way to return the last 2 digits from an integer:

```
integer = (Date.today + 6).year
# => 2015
integer.to_s[-2..-1].to_i
# => 15
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad to be of help! Check out Alok's answer as well - it's more succinct if you wish to interface with the date directly rather than an integer.

Answer (score 1):

So many ways...

```
(Date.today+6).to_s[2,2].to_i #=> 15
```

@Jordan gets my vote, however.